# Why isn't Bounded a subclass of Enum in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

It seems like any Bounded instance should have a sane implementation of Enum. I cannot personally think of a counterexample, although if someone comes up with one that isn't pathological then I will understand why this isn't the case.

From doing `:i` on the two typeclasses it seems like the only exception currently in the standard library is for tuples, which are Bounded but not Enums. However any Bounded tuple must also be Enumerable in a sane way, by simply incrementing the last element and then wrapping around when it gets to maxBound.

This change would probably also involve adding `predB` and `nextB` or something like that to Bounded for a safe/looping way to traverse through the Enum values. In this case `toEnum 0 :: (...)` would be equal to `(toEnum 0, toEnum 0, ...) :: (...)`

Comment: Can't really answer this authoritatively but consider the range of all real numbers between 0 and 1. It has clear lower and upper bounds but it has uncountably infinite members.

Comment: @Doval that is a fair point. However the same could be said about all real numbers in general (uncountably infinite members), but `Double` / `Float` and all similar types implement `Enum` anyway, they just make `succ = (+ 1)` and `fromEnum = truncate`. Haskell's way does actually make sense from a practicality perspective as otherwise [0, 0.5..] and similar wouldn't work, so it seems Haskell does not worry about countability when it comes to Enums.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `succ` is `(+1)`. That's strange, because `Double` and `Float` do not have infinite precision and thus *are* enumerable - `succ` could've been defined to be +1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

Comment: @Doval I think the reason for that was because the Haskell core team wanted [1..] to mean the same thing with Doubles that it means with Ints.

Comment: @semicolon doubles and floats are not Real numbers (e.g. can not store PI in a double without losing some precision) so they are enumerable

Comment: @jk I mean unless they are complex they are definitely real. But I get what you are saying. But that is not really valid reasoning, seeing as Data.Ratio has theoretically limitless precision, and while I know you can use the diagonal method to enumerate all of them, Haskell does not do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One practical example I like comes from the world of programming languages: the set of types in an OO system is bounded and discrete but not enumerable, and partially ordered but not totally ordered.

The partial ordering in question is the subtyping relation `<:`. The upper bound would then be the *top type* (which C# calls `object` and Scala calls `Any`), and the lower bound would be the *bottom type* (Scala's `Nothing`; C#/Java have no equivalent to speak of).

However, there is no way to enumerate all the types in the type system, so you can't write an `instance Enum Type`. After all, users can write their own types so there's no way to know what they'll be in advance. You can enumerate all the types in any given program, but not in the whole system.

Likewise, (according to a certain reasonable definition of subtyping,) `<:` is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric but *not total*. There are pairs of types which are unrelated by `<:`. (`Cat` and `Dog` are both subtypes of `Animal`, but neither is a subtype of the other.)

---

Suppose that we're writing a compiler for a simple OO language. Here's the representation of types in our system:

```
data Type = Bottom | Class { name :: String, parent :: Type } | Top
```

And the definition of the subtyping relation:

```
(<:) :: Type -> Type -> Bool
Bottom <: _ = True
Class _ _ <: Bottom = False
Class n t <: s@(Class m _)
    | n == m = True  -- you can't have different classes with the same name in this hypothetical language
    | otherwise = t <: s  -- try to find s in the parents of this class
Class _ _ <: Top = True
Top <: Top = True
Top <: _ = False
```

This also gives us a supertyping relation.

```
(>:) :: Type -> Type -> Bool
t >: s = s <: t
```

You can also find the least upper bound of two types,

```
lub :: Type -> Type -> Type
lub Bottom s = s
lub t Bottom = t
lub t@(Class _ p) s@(Class _ q) =
    | t >: s = t
    | t <: s = s
    | p >: s = p
    | t <: q = q
    | otherwise = lub p q
lub Top _ = Top
lub _ Top = Top
```

Exercise: show that `Type` forms a [bounded complete poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_complete_poset) two ways, under `<:` and under `>:`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! That answers my question completely and also answers my follow up question about Ord. Would Eq have similar issues? Where a non-equatable type might have a maxBound or a minBound. In this case should Cat == Dog just return false, as they are different classes, or would it be undecidable because of the tree position puts neither above or below the other?

Comment: An ordering implies an equality - just define `x == y = x <= y && y <= x`. If I were designing a `Poset` class I'd have `class Eq a => Poset a`. A quick Google confirms that [other people have had the same idea](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/altfloat-0.3.1/docs/Data-Poset.html).

Comment: Sorry my question was ambiguous. What I meant was whether Bounded implied Eq even if it doesn't imply Ord.

Comment: @semicolon Again there's no relationship between the two classes. Consider `data Bound a = Min | Val a | Max` which augments a type `a` with `+∞` and `-∞` elements. By construction `Bound a` can always be made an instance of `Bounded` but it'd only be equatable if the underlying type `a` is

Comment: alright fair enough. I guess one example could be functions that take and return values of type `Double`, where `const (1/0)` is `maxBound` and `const (negate 1/0)` is `minBound` but `\x -> 1 - x` and `\x -> x - 1` are incomparable.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the operations are independent, so tying them together with a subclass relationship doesn't actually buy you anything.  Say you wanted to create a custom type that implemented `Bounded`, perhaps `Doubles` constrained between a max and min, but you had no need for any of the `Enum` operations.  If `Bounded` were a subclass, you would have to implement all the `Enum` functions anyway, just to get it to compile.

It doesn't really matter if there's a reasonable implementation for `Enum`, or any other number of typeclasses.  If you don't actually need it, you shouldn't be forced to implement it.

Contrast this with say, `Ord` and `Eq`.  There, the `Ord` operations are dependent on the `Eq` ones, so it makes sense to require the subclass to avoid duplication and ensure consistency.

Comment: But what about the whole Monad, Applicative, Functor deal? They don't depend on each other do they?

Comment: In those cases, it's part of the definition.  All monads are also applicatives and functors by definition, so you can't fulfill the monad "contract" without fulfilling the others.  I'm not familiar enough with the math to know if that's a fundamental relationship or an imposed definition, but either way, we're stuck with it now.

Comment: Right... and you can't fulfill the Bounded contract without fulfilling Enum as far as I can tell. It also seems like you can't fulfill the Bounded contract without fulfilling the Ord contract, as how can an unordered type have a max and a min?

Comment: @semicolon The [documentation for `Bounded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) says "Ord is not a superclass of Bounded since types that are not totally ordered may also have upper and lower bounds."

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Didn't even think about partially ordered types. +1 for a non-pathological example and for quoting the documentation.

Comment: What is an example of such a partially ordered type? In that case I understand why Ord is not a superclass of Bounded. Although I am still unsure about the Enum part, so far I haven't come up with a good counterexample.

Comment: @semicolon An example of a partial ordering from the world of computers might be subtyping in OO languages. Writing `<:` for _is a subtype of_, `∀ T S. T <: S ∨ S <: T` does not hold (eg, `int !<: bool ∧ bool !<: int`). You'd likely run into this if you were writing a compiler.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson ah ok. So for example if A is a superclass of B and C, and D is a subclass of B and C, then B and C are incomparable but A and D are max/min?

Comment: @semicolon I'll elaborate in an answer.